# Function that returns any type of number?

Tags: c#, function

Apologizing for the simple question as I'm still learning C#, is there a way to use one function that does some math, and returns the output but not having to create multiple functions (each for different types)? So instead of copying and pasting the same function and changing 'int' to 'float' and 'double' etc, **can I make them all work within 1 function?**

So I don't have to have:

```
public int DoMath(int input) {

    //do stuff
    //return some int
}

public float DoMath(float input) {

    //do stuff
    //return some int
}
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled I doubt this will work, as you'd have to do something like `where T : ...` and there's no base-type for numbers ... :(

Comment: In an ideal world, you'd use generics. Sadly, there's no way to constrain a generic type to just numeric types, so there's no practical way of achieving this.

Comment: That's something I'd love to have in some future version of C#, but at the time of writing there's no way to create a "generic template for a set of types".

Comment: Thanks, those were all helpful. On the other hand, can I do some stuff inside to ensure it's an int/float?

Comment: @user2949024 inside *what*? if you define the parameter to be of type `int` then there's no chance to provide another type ... I do not understand your question!

Comment: An alternative, although a bit messy, would be to pass the numeric values in as an object, and then use a case statement combined with typeof() in order to do the correct casts followed by calculations on the numeric value. I would provide a code example but i cannot because this is now a duplicate!

Comment: I've put it in a pastebin for you http://pastebin.com/EqJF3HFZ

Comment: @LexWebb don't forget to mention the performance penalty when (un)boxing value types ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair That is a good point! I did not know how expensive that was until now.